# How does the S flip case work?

Tags: samsung, battery-life

I know that the magnets turn the phone on and off, but what about the time/date display on the case? Does the case somehow use the phone's battery to display those? If so, does it not drain the battery faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data is attributed to an online manual for the device at this location:

http://gadgetguideonline.com/s8/galaxy-s8-led-wallet-cover-guide/

NFC powers the device, and is estimated to have minimal draw to the phone battery.

See the quote from the forum thread below the manual:

---

> No, you cannot turn off the display. The LED cover is powered through
>   NFC. Once you snap the cover on, it will drain power. But power
>   required is very marginal. It should not affect the battery life of
>   the phone.

---

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't drain the battery anymore than having no case. As far as I know, it just uses the AMOLED display to show the time and date, or whatever you have it set to display, and the case is designed to be able to see through it enough to see the info.